# Descartar números y cualquier string contenido en brackets (brackets incluidos) Regex

Tags: regex

estoy intentando encontrar una expresión regular que solo me seleccione strings fuera de brackets y sin números.
Por ejemplo:
**Palabra123
Amarillo Naranja (Azul Verde)
Amarillo Naranja (Verde)
Amarillo (Azul)**

Debería seleccionar sólo:
Palabra
Amarillo Naranja
Amarillo Naranja
Amarillo

Necesito que además se ignore el espacio que existe entre la última palabra y el primer paréntesis abierto.
He llegado a la siguiente expresión regular: ^[a-zA-Z ]*
Pero el problema es que no soy capaz de que ignore el espacio entre la última palabra a la izquierda del "("

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿qué expresión regular es la que has intentado? ¿Sería una solución válida usar una función que haga `.split()` por expresiones regulares? En ese caso podrías usar como expresión regular lo que va entre parentesis para dividir la cadena, y luego juntar los trozos resultantes.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega el código que has realizado por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

## En una sola regrex

Puedes usar:

```js
let re = /(?<= |^)[a-z\d]+(?= |$)/gi

let str = 'Palabra123 Amarillo Naranja (Azul Verde) Amarillo Naranja (Verde) Amarillo (Azul) Naranja'

console.log(str.match(re));
// Si quieres en un solo string en vez de un array puedes usar: str.match(re).join(' ')
```

Lo que hace esta expresión es buscar las palabras que cumplan las 2 cosas siguientes al mismo tiempo:

- Tengan un espacio al inicio   o bien sean la primera palabra `^`.
- Tengan un espacio al final   o sean la última palabra `$`.

## En dos regrex

Es si tu lenguaje no acepta las expresiones del tipo [LookBehind `(?<=y)x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions)

Es recomendable partir tu regrex en 2 para que sea más fácil de leer:

- La primera encuentra todos las expresiones de la forma `(A)` y las sustituye por la nada: `''`.
- Luego obteenemos los grupos de palabras que nos interesan.

```js
let catchParenthesis = /\(.*?\)/g

let catchWords = /[a-z\d]+/ig

let str = 'Palabra123 Amarillo Naranja (Azul Verde) Amarillo Naranja (Verde) Amarillo (Azul)'

console.log(str.replace(catchParenthesis, '').match(catchWords));
```